# Visually Scrambling a String While Keeping It Equally Valid

Tags: javascript, string

This is more of a for-fun thing, but because I'm curious.. (This is essentially obfuscation, but I'm explaining it so everybody can take something from it)

Say we have a string ( ~ In JavaScript):

`var str = "stackoverflow`

Now, also say that this string should be visually obscured so that if you were to read through you wouldn't just see `stackoverflow` there, and instead something a little harder to simply read. I was thinking about putting it into a numerical form, and then just convert it to be read like any other string. No idea if it's possible, but I'll try it because it's interesting.

So, my question, is how would you personally do that, while keeping the string completely valid? I personally tried putting in a bunch of Regex that really did nothing for my own fun. Again, this is more of a because-I'm-curious type of thing, and probably won't get used.

Example:

```
var str = `s./\\t./ack;
```

Output:

`stack`

Obviously that code is entirely improbable, but it just illustrates what I'm looking at.

Comment: can you give a before and after of what you mean?

Comment: convert it to binary! can easily be done natively in javascript

Comment: That's a great suggestion. For some fun I'll try it, along with the character entity suggestion, and I'll see how it works out!

Comment: Base64? Substitution cipher? Actual encryption? What's the real goal?

Comment: The goal is simply not being able to read the string in plain text in the code, but it can be used like a normal string by the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is quite common. Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't provide native Base64 support, but you can find [encoding](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode) and [decoding](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_decode) functions over at PHPJS.

Example:

```
var str = "c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdw";
alert(base64_decode(str)); // alerts "stackoverflow"
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Charmander (love the name ^_^), some browsers (Firefox, Chrome...) do in fact support Base64. They just have really weird names for the functions: `btoa()` to encode and `atob()` to decode.

Comment: Note that certain browsers provide `btoa` and `atob` for encoding and decoding, respectively; use those if available.

Comment: Ah, I like this one. I'll give this a look. I'm wondering what other possibilities there are for encoding and decoding, oh course hashing is out of the question.. I'll spend some time researching

Comment: Huh, well consider me corrected.

Comment: Im using Titanium right now, I'll give Base64 a look in the API docs. Also, awesome name @Charmander EDIT: Native Base64 support apparently, I think this one is great for the simplicity while being equally effective

Comment: I'd say that I prefer this option (Base64), just because it's by far the easiest to implement and simply keeps the code out of plain text without bothering to go deep into obfuscation, and is handy to know =D

Answer (score 1):

You could encode each character as a character entity:

```
"\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0063\u006b\u006f\u0076\u0065\u0072\u0066\u006c\u006f\u0077"
```

It is largely pointless for obfuscation (if that is your goal) but as requested, `stackoverflow` is no longer visible in the string. A function to perform the encoding:

```
function uniencode(str) {
    function pad(str) {
        return Array(5 - str.length).join('0') + str;
    }

    return Array.prototype.map.call(str, function(c) {
        return '\\u' + pad(c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
    }).join('');
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, how do you think you can take that and convert it to it's unicode equivalent?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it'll automatically be parsed and read as the characters they represent.

Comment: @JTApps: Kolink is correct; the decoding is automatic. Unicode escapes in strings are a part of the JavaScript syntax. I have also provided a function to perform the encoding.

Comment: You may want to adjust your encoder function to take into account that older browsers don't support `Array.map`.

Comment: @Kolink: I may, but the encoder is meant to be used during development, and I should hope no-one here is developing on Internet Explorer 8. (Or lower.)

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I kinda forgot about that. Fair enough. -throws PokéBall- :p

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx

```
var _0x6ee4=["\x73\x74\x61\x63\x6B\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77"];
var str=_0x6ee4[0];
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `_0x6ee4` variable?

Comment: @Kolink there is no purpose, its obfuscation :P

Comment: @jbabey I enjoyed that comment

Comment: Obfuscation is supposed to obfuscate from the human, not the computer...

Comment: @Kolink "visually obscured so that if you were to read through you wouldn't just see stackoverflow there, and instead something a little harder to simply read." - i think the OP is talking about obfuscation.

Comment: Instead of using Obfuscation I explained it in simple terms so that everybody would understand =D

Comment: Notice how @Kolink used the word "obfuscation". He probably understands.

Comment: Clarified a little bit.. just was looking for something easy that simply keeps it out of plaintext, but doesn't have to delve deeply into obfuscation. Seemed like Base64 was a good choice because of the simplicity